# How to debug an unexpected time gap in browser network operations in ReactJs/Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, redux

I'm using React/Redux for my app, the app is bundled in the main.5ae1d536.js file. As you can see, there is quite a big gap (almost 1 second!) between the download of the app and the rest of the downloads. The rest of the downloads is basically images, and other HTTP requests that are shot upon app launch.

I have done a lot of testing on the React app, and I'm sure everything is running just fine. And still, I can't figure out what that gap can be, getting rid of it or reducing it at least would dramatically improve response time on my app.

What do you think?

[image]

Update, including profiler screenshot. The way the rest of downloads are triggered are through various `componentDidMount` lifecycle methods. Others seem to be triggered by modernizr as the screenshot shows or are calls to retrieve font files or images needed by React generated HTML.

[image]

Comment: How are the "one-second delayed" assets being called from react source?  We may need to see your bundler setup, but my guess is that the main bundle is getting downloaded, decompressed, processed, and then executed which then calls the other assets.  This process appears to be taking about a second.  Run the page through the profiler in the chrome inspector and show us that.  I think we will see Javascript getting processed in the interim second

Comment: @JosephFurlott Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question with more info. From what I understand, the javascript download actually finishes at around 500ms as shown on the screenshot. I was suspecting the decompressing and processing but it surprises me that React takes 1 whole second to go through a few fetch calls before fully rendering the page.

Comment: well that answers some of the problems then.  The delay for the assets are just really the components mounting.  You do not necessarily need to do server side rendering, but maybe you can meet in the middle by editing your index.html and bundling assets better.  I *think* you can get really optimized using webpack and importing you files so that they get bundled.  You can even take it a step further by using their code splitting function to reduce the  bundle that has to get mounted on all page loads

Answer (score 1):

You should use server side rendering of your react app. Then the browser gets proper html and can request additional resources immediately (as they are linked from the generated html). Without ssr the browser has to download and run the JS first before additional resources can be identified and requested.

Take a google for reactjs server side rendering. It is a bit tricky to set up but worth the hustle as it also improves google ranking. Without ssr google just sees a blank page as it doesn't evaluate JS.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. 
So, the running of JS on browser side takes one second, that's normal?
For my purposes, no need for server side rendering as the part of the app I'm talking about is for logged-in users, i.e. Google doesn't need to crawl it.
I guess I will just settle for this for now.

Comment: It's hard to know how long the running of the Javascript takes without seeing your app, but that seems very possible for a midsized app.  Without seeing the code, it's hard to make an assumption like that.  Server side rendering isn't only useful for crawlers, it definitely can be helpful for loading assets like this like @edlerd says